inlining function
I want to inline a function using PRAGMA INLINE but I am not sure how to check if it worked as I expect.
More exactly, I have a function:
create or replace function my_fnc(p1 varchar2, p2 varchar2) return varchar2
is
begin
    RETURN p1||p2;
end my_fnc;

... its overloading
create or replace function my_fnc(p1 varchar2, p2 varchar2, p3 varchar2) return varchar2
is
begin
    RETURN p1||p2||p3;
end my_fnc;

... and the following code
set serveroutput on
declare
    var1 varchar2(50);
    var2 varchar2(50);
begin
    pragma inline(my_fnc, 'YES');
    select my_fnc('aaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbb', 'ccccccccc')
         , my_fnc('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy')
      into var1
         , var2
      from dual;

    dbms_output.put_line('var1 = ' || var1 || ' / var2 = ' ||var2);
end;

My question is: will pragma inline work on this way (I saw it used only like var1 := my_fnc(...))
If it is working, will the inlining be applied for both calls or just for the 1st (I saw that PRAGMA INIT should be addressed everytime the function is called))
How can I check when it is used the PRAGMA INLINING?

The documentation has an example "Specifying that Overloaded Subprogram Is To Be Inlined" which says:

the INLINE pragma affects both functions

And the same section says:

If subprogram is overloaded, then the preceding pragma applies to every subprogram with that name.

However, it also says:

Subprogram inlining replaces a subprogram invocation with a copy of the invoked subprogram (if the invoked and invoking subprograms are in the same program unit).

You are calling the standalone function from an anonymous block, not "the same program unit", so neither will be inlined here.
If you were defining the functions in a package and then calling them from within the same package, or defining them locally in your anonymous block, then lining might apply, but in your example it doesn't.
A select into also isn't in the list of statements the documentation says the pragma affects.
You can look at the PL/SQL hierarchical profiler to investigate whether and how your code is being optimised.
